# What's the best Stack Exchange to discuss language analysis?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I don't mean to discuss the grammar of [English language](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq), but rather its lexical analysis.

Comment: Could you give a sample question of what you'd like to ask?

Comment: What is "edit distance"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [site proposal for natural language processing and computational linguistics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2761/natural-language-processing-and-computational-linguistics-nlp-cl). It's not clear that it will proceed into being a site on its own, because there are already sites that cover these topics:

- The [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) site covers language analysis, including [computational linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/tags/computational-linguistics) and [natural language processing](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp).
- The [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) site also covers language analysis from a computational perspective.

The concept of [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) as I know it and how Wikipedia describes it is part of formal language analysis and thus a CS topic. If there is a different meaning pertaining to natural languages, the Linguistics site would be a good place to ask about it.

Answer (score 4):

https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/ seems like the closest match